# Remove element after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a div element that is being the after the modal close which makes my screen unresponsive.

```
               <div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>
```

When I remove the attribute from console through below command it works.

```
                    $( ".modal-backdrop" ).remove();
```

But when I add this on success of ajax call it doesn't. Shall I handle this differently?

Below is the ajax call:

```
     function saveParty(){
     var hasError = validateParty();
     if(!hasError){
     var data = loadPartyDetails();
      var objectID = $("#objectID").val();
      $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "/saveDetails/" + objectID + "/",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
       timeout : 100000,
       success : function(result) {
             $("#detailsPanel").html(result);
         document.getElementById("successMsgParties").style.display="";
          $('#successMsgParties').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
          },
     error : function(e) {
         console.log("ERROR: ", e);
          },
     done : function(e) {
         console.log("DONE");
         }
     });

    }
```

I have putting remove line code in done and after ajax call completed.

Comment: Do you have an example of the ajax call?

Comment: `success of ajax call` - perhaps ajax call failed

Comment: Please post code of your AJAX call

Comment: Those are the 3 classes on that div 

modal-backdrop fade show

my guess is you need to remove the show from the class list

Comment: Updated the ajax call

Comment: You need to add `$( ".modal-backdrop" ).remove();` to the `success:` callback function of your AJAX Call, it's currently missing.

Comment: Where is your modal close command in success handler. write this in success portion $(".modal-backdrop" ).remove();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to write this in success response:

```
$(".modal-backdrop" ).hide();
```

Or make html empty using `empty()`:

```
$(".modal-backdrop" ).empty();
```

Or make html empty:

```
$(".modal-backdrop" ).html('');
```

Answer (score 0):

write this in success portion

```
$(".modal-backdrop" ).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to use below at multiple places to make it work.

```
      $(".modal-backdrop" ).remove();
```